# How to keep np.array properties in pandas dataframe where elements are arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I want to use a dataframe as a sort of database where elements of it are numpy arrays and I want to keep their properties for later use in dataframe operations.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

names=["randomname"]*4
identifiers=["a","b","b","c"]
arrays=[np.arange(0,10),np.arange(20,30),np.arange(22,32),np.arange(40,50)]
alltogether=np.array([names,identifiers,arrays])
df=pd.DataFrame(data=alltogether.T,columns=["names","id","arrays"])
```

This gives me somewhat the desired Dataframe.

However I want to be able to use DataFrame indexing logic together with plotting.

For example

```py
df[df["id"]=="b"].plot()
```

this currently gives

```
TypeError: no numeric data to plot
```

Now can anybody help on how to still keep this element  consisting of a np.array ?

Ideally my indexing logic would enable me to plot multiple of the arrays with certain criteria(here id=b)

I am kinda lost

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

```
In [38]: names=["randomname"]*4
    ...: identifiers=["a","b","b","c"]
    ...: arrays=[np.arange(0,10),np.arange(20,30),np.arange(22,32),np.arange(40,
    ...: 50)]
    ...: alltogether=np.array([names,identifiers,arrays])
    ...: df=pd.DataFrame(data=alltogether.T,columns=["names","id","arrays"])
<ipython-input-38-f2bc5f6c3a15>:4: VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray.
  alltogether=np.array([names,identifiers,arrays])
```

Did you get this warning? Does it bother you?  It's produced by that `alltogether` line.  You are mixing strings and arrays, and result has to be an `object` dtype array.

Anyways, the result (which you should have shown :(  ):

```
In [39]: df
Out[39]: 
        names id                                    arrays
0  randomname  a            [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
1  randomname  b  [20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29]
2  randomname  b  [22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31]
3  randomname  c  [40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49]
In [40]: df.dtypes
Out[40]: 
names     object
id        object
arrays    object
dtype: object
In [41]: alltogether
Out[41]: 
array([['randomname', 'randomname', 'randomname', 'randomname'],
       ['a', 'b', 'b', 'c'],
       [array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]),
        array([20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29]),
        array([22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31]),
        array([40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49])]], dtype=object)
In [42]: df['arrays'].to_numpy()
Out[42]: 
array([array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]),
       array([20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29]),
       array([22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31]),
       array([40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49])], dtype=object)
```

Selecting a couple of rows:

```
In [46]: df[df['id']=='b']
Out[46]: 
        names id                                    arrays
1  randomname  b  [20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29]
2  randomname  b  [22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31]
```

What is the `plot` method supposed to do?  I haven't used it

I can make a simple line plot from a frame like this:

```
In [58]: adf = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(5)**2)
In [59]: adf
Out[59]: 
    0
0   0
1   1
2   4
3   9
4  16
In [60]: adf.plot()
```

But that has one number per cell, not strings (your `id` and `names` columns) or arrays.

I could use `matplotlib` plot function calls on the individual array elements of your frame.  But a simple call the dataframe plot method won't do it.

```
In [68]: df[df['id']=='b']['arrays'].to_numpy()
Out[68]: 
array([array([20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29]),
       array([22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31])], dtype=object)
In [69]: plt.plot(_[0],_[1])
Out[69]: [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x7f3915e6bfd0>]
```

This uses the 20:30 range as `x` axis, and `22:32` as `y`.